# Java scanner advances line and returns input understanding query

Tags: java, class, scanning

This is more of a function question which I am attempting to ask as clear as possible.

Java handbook states:

> `nextLine()`:  **Advances** this scanner past the current line and **returns** the input that was skipped.

Code for example:

```
    // Create new scanner class myObj, receive System.in from user.
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Print prompt for user.
    System.out.println("Enter");
    
    //Allocate myObj input from System.in into userName string.      
    String userName = myObj.nextLine();
    
    //Print output of userName, myObj or System.in input.
    System.out.print (userName);
```

I am trying to understand which lines are being advanced over with the scanner function and what is being skipped I understand what is occurring but not why.

Comment: _specifically_, it reads from the input stream until it hits the next linefeed/newline (which IIRC is platform-dependent; on windows it would be the sequence `\r\n`, but on linux it would be `\n`. For most practical purposes it shouldn't matter much), stopping once it's just passed said newline and returning everything it passed over in the process of getting there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition of `nextLine()` as per JDK7.

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

Look, when you call `nextLine()`, it moves the pointer(think of it as the point from where the scanner start scanning), to the next line, that is, it skips the current line. Then the `nextLine()` returns, whatever it has skipped.

Therefore, when you call,

```
String userName = myObj.nextLine();
```

The program skips whatever the user has entered after the last line separation (here, after the program prints, "Enter") and moves to the next line. Then the `nextLine()` method returns the skipped data in the form of a string.